# Sorting an array (incl subarray) in Angular 4 for a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

My team and I are creating an Audience Response Web Application with Angular 4. I am creating an array with the name *allAnswers* which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgDQ4.png) . When I end a quiz I am routed to the results component which shows me this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQd3L.png). As you can see the answers are messed up. This is the [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH15c.png) of my table component.

Let me explain the structure of the array *allAnswers*. An answer is built out of an:

0 element:

- this is where the questionID stands for which the answer is for

1 element:

- answer: this is a simple boolean bc right now we just have true/false questions implemented
- studentID: a string which identifies a single student in a quiz

As you can see in the picture of the table we want to structure it as follows:

The first table head element is named "Frage" which means question. the column under it contains the questionIDs, which will be later replaced by the question text (which is not the problem right now). The next table headers are the studentsID, in the row in which they have joined a Quiz (a seperate array which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCV0t.png)). Now we want to sort the *allAnswers* array so that that it correctly shows the answer of each student fitting to the right answer.

How can that be solved?

Comment: Can you add your code to https://stackblitz.com/ and post here?

Comment: I can't see any of the images in imgur but it sounds like it can be done simply by a basic filter() function. return the questions, filter answers for each question and show whatever

Comment: For sorting Lodash could be helpful. You can use it to define the sort conditions by yourself. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Comment: Hey, thank you for your replies, but I already figured it out. I thought about implementing a pipe, but then a collegue mentioned ng-template (former ng-container) and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies, but I already figured it out. I thought about implementing a pipe, but then a colleague mentioned ng-template (former ng-container) and now it works. I restructured my [allAnswers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjoIf.png) array, so it contained studentID, questionID and answer on one level. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7c06.png) is the code in html which made it all magically work.

If you have any suggestions of making it look more clean, please write :). I'm still a beginner, started with Angular a few months before.